# Complex Sort for Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

So I have been working on this task for a while now and I've hit a problem. I have tried and rewritten over and over and can't seem to come up with a good enough solution to this.

I am trying to sort one array of objects into another array of objects. I am using knockout but the solution does not have to incorporate knockout if it can be done more directly in vanilla JS or jQuery.

I'll explain:

We start with an observableArray `serials` with some serial number objects in it. This array always contains this format:

```
var serials = ko.observableArray([
    { number: "DFG09008", qty: 1 }, 
    { number: "DFG09009", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09010", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09011", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09020", qty: 1 },
    { number: "ASD-0001", qty: 1 },
    { number: "ASD-0002", qty: 1 },
    { number: "HJ-DRT-06", qty: 1 },
    { number: "HJ-DRT-07", qty: 1 },
    { number: "POU055054", qty: 1 }
]);
// qty property is for something unrelated to this in the app
```

The desired outcome of the function I am writing is that it would output to another observableArray `displaySerials` that would be used to present the idea of a 'numerical range':

```
var displaySerials = ko.observableArray([
    { beginSerial: "DFG09008", endSerial: "DFG09011" },
    { beginSerial: "DFG09020", endSerial: "" },
    { beginSerial: "ASD-0001", endSerial: "ASD-0002" },
    { beginSerial: "HJ-DRT-06", endSerial: "HJ-DRT-07" },
    { beginSerial: "POU055054", endSerial: "" }
]);
```

So, because `serials`' first four members' `number` property, `"DFG09008", "DFG09009", "DFG09010", "DFG09011"` have a matching prefix (`DFG090`) and suffix numbers that are contiguous (`8, 9, 10, 11`), they are put into an object where `beginSerial` is the lowest number in the range (`DFG09008`) and `endSerial` is the highest (`DFG09011`). Notice that `"DFG09020"` is put in a separate object. This is because it is not consecutive with the other numbers in the group so it is considered by itself.

Any serial number that is unrelated to the rest of the group is put into it's own object, where the `endSerial` property is an empty string: `{ beginSerial: "DFG09020", endSerial: "" }`

The only defined rule for the way serial numbers are structured is that **they will always end with a number**. But there could be tens or hundreds in the collection.

Only requirements for a valid solution are the things mentioned above as well as:

- The array `serials` should remain unmodified through the course of this functionality.
- The solution is not specific or dependent on any string structure for the serials, except that they end with a number.

[My jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4b1mp2f/1/)

Any contribution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have not included the way you're currently sorting in the question itself yet. Could you please add it, and tell us where the specific problem lies? (Also, you would benefit ***a lot*** here from unit tests. Convert your human readable spec to automated tests: it'll be worth your while for sure!)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need to *sort* them so much as *group* them. They seem already to be in order. All you need to do is walk through the list and see if each one is sequential to the previous one. If it is, it's the end of the displaySerial you're building; if not, you start a new displaySerial.

Maybe the tricky part is determining whether they're sequential. I chose to use a regular expression to split the trailing numbers off. It's sequential if the non-numeric parts are equal and the numbers of one different.

There's no need for Knockout or jQuery in this. You're not doing anything with the DOM. You could use utility functions, but there's not much reason to. I've used Knockout just to display the results.

If you *do* need to sort them, you would use a comparison function with the same regexp splitter, comparing the non-numeric part first, and the numeric if the non-numerics were equal.

```js
// test data
var serials = [
    { number: "DFG09008", qty: 1 }, 
    { number: "DFG09009", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09010", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09011", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09020", qty: 1 },
    { number: "ASD-0001", qty: 1 },
    { number: "ASD-0002", qty: 1 },
    { number: "HJ-DRT-06", qty: 1 },
    { number: "HJ-DRT-07", qty: 1 },
    { number: "POU055054", qty: 1 }
];


// constructor for displaySerials array
function DisplaySerial (beginSerial, endSerial) {
    this.beginSerial = beginSerial;
    this.endSerial = endSerial;
}

var serialPartsPattern = /(.*\D)(\d+)$/;
function isSequential(s1, s2) {
    if (s1 === undefined) return false;
    var m1 = s1.match(serialPartsPattern),
        m2 = s2.match(serialPartsPattern);
    return m1[1] === m2[1] && (+m1[2] + 1) === +m2[2]; 
}

var displaySerials = [],
    currentSerial,
    prevSerial,
    currentDisplaySerial;
for (var i=0; i<serials.length; ++i) {
    currentSerial = serials[i].number;
    if (isSequential(prevSerial, currentSerial)) {
        currentDisplaySerial.endSerial = currentSerial;
    }
    else {
        currentDisplaySerial = new DisplaySerial(currentSerial, "");
        displaySerials.push(currentDisplaySerial);
    }
    prevSerial = currentSerial;
}

ko.applyBindings({displaySerials: displaySerials});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ol data-bind="foreach:displaySerials">
  <li><span data-bind="text:beginSerial"></span>...<span data-bind="text:endSerial"></span></li>
  </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a [lodash](http://www.lodash.com) based solution. I assumed your values are not necessarily sorted. Note that I added more values to show it sorts and groups properly and I changed the order.

```js
var serials = [
    { number: "DFG09008", qty: 1 }, 
    { number: "DFG09009", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09016", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09010", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09011", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09005", qty: 1 }, 
    { number: "DFG09014", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09015", qty: 1 },
    { number: "DFG09020", qty: 1 },
    { number: "ASD-0001", qty: 1 },
    { number: "ASD-0002", qty: 1 },
    { number: "HJ-DRT-06", qty: 1 },
    { number: "HJ-DRT-07", qty: 1 },
    { number: "POU055054", qty: 1 }
];

var splitSerials = _.map(serials, function(serial){
  var parts = serial.number.match(/([^\d]+)(\d+)/);
  return {key: parts[1], number: parts[2]};
});

var grouped = _.groupBy(splitSerials, 'key');

function chunkConsec(array){
  return _.transform(array, function(result, n){
    if(_.last(_.last(result)) === n - 1){
      _.last(result).push(n);
    } else {
      result.push([n]);
    }
    return true;
  });
}

function unchunk(array){
  if(array.length > 1){
    return [_.first(array), _.last(array)];
  } else {
    return array;
  }
}

var groupedArray = _.mapValues(grouped,
  _.flow(
    _.partial(_.map, _, 'number'),
    _.partial(_.map, _, _.parseInt),
    _.sortBy,
    chunkConsec,
    _.partial(_.map, _, unchunk)
  ));

function buildRange(value, key){
  var result = {beginSerial: (key + value[0])};
  result.endSerial = (value.length > 1 ? key + value[1] : '');
  return result;
}
function buildRanges(values, key){
  return _.map(values, function(value){
    return buildRange(value, key);
  });
}

var finalResult = _.flatten(_.values(_.mapValues(groupedArray, buildRanges)));
console.log(finalResult);
alert(JSON.stringify(finalResult));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```